# =IF(OR(AND - How to make gantt with automatic calendar handle start date prior to 31th of Dec and end date later than 1st of Jan

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-workspace

I made a gantt template where tasks are entered with a start date and an end date. Based on that I get a week number and use it to automatically fill cells  in the calendar part of the sheet.

[image]

As our company have a fiscal year that start on the 1/7 and end on the 30/6. I run in to problems when the start date is less then or equal to 52 and end date is equal or bigger than 1. Can someone help me solve this?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1etVR3Y-l1hTVi7afdLJArq0juBFkXVI04r0SWwuAfCU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is a place to get answers about software programming, not about using and setting up spreadsheets. You need to find a different forum that is intended to answer questions of this nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF($A8 > $B8,
              IF(OR(AE$3>=$A8,AE$3<=$B8),"Y",""),
              IF(AND(AE$3>=$A8,AE$3<=$B8),"Y","")
 )
```

I just added an outer IF to calculate if the start week was greater than the end week. If so, instead of using AND, it uses OR.

Comment: Thats odd, I tested it with a copy of your sample. Just tested again and works fine. Here it is on one line just in case it is something weird with the new lines, also copying here the formula as it would be in cell C4  `=IF($A4 > $B4, IF(OR(C$3>=$A4,C$3<=$B4),"Y",""),  IF(AND(C$3>=$A4,C$3<=$B4),"Y",""))`

Comment: I must have messed something up, I tried it again and i worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from the Google community that I got to work

Here's the formula:

=if(($B4 >= $A4) * (C$3>=$A4) * (C$3<=$B4) + ($B4 < $A4) * ((C$3>=$A4) * (C$3 <= 52) + (C$3<=$B4)) = 0,, "Y")

or delete all the formulas in C4:BB and use this one formula in C4 without copying to the other cells.
=ArrayFormula(if((B4:B >= A4:A) * (C3:BB3>=A4:A) * (C3:BB3<=B4:B) + (B4:B < A4:A) * ((C3:BB3>=A4:A) * (C3:BB3 <= 52) + (C3:BB3<=B4:B)) = 0,, "Y"))